# Passando array como parâmetro de uma função

Tags: array, c++, funções, parâmetros

Como passar uma *array* para uma função sem que eu tenha que informar a quantidade de índices que a mesma possui?

#### Informando o tamanho

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

void imprimir(int _array[], int _tamanho) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _tamanho; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", _array[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    imprimir(myArray, 5);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

## Sem o tamanhho

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

void imprimir(int _array[]) {
    // Aqui ele deve ser capaz de descobrir sozinho o tamanho da array.
    int tamanho = _array[].tamanho; // Apenas uma abstração.

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho ; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", _array[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    imprimir(myArray);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de dar inteligencia ao meu programa para que ele seja capaz de descobrir sozinho o tamanho da *array* sem que eu tenha que passá-lo como parâmetro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se está usando C++ use os recursos da linguagem e adote o `vector` que é uma abstração, essencialmente sem custo, correta nesta linguagem, ele tem inúmeras vantagens. Não programe em C quando está usando C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void imprimir(vector<int> &array) {
    for (int item : array) cout << item << ' ';
}

int main() {
    vector<int> myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    imprimir(myArray);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Gu6nqD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dqmgsveg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Parameter.cpp).

Mas se quiser fazer do jeito C então passe o tamanho sempre. Ou crie você uma abstração que ele vá junto, mas será recriar o `vector` só que um jeito certamente pior. Ou use uma constante global com o tamanho, já que neste caso você sabe e use dentro da sua função, mas isso é fácil cometer erro, nada disso compensa. Só não use um número como terminador, a não ser que seja exatamente o que precisa.